# "Definitely" + "will be able to"

Tags: word-usage

Can "definitely" somehow pair with "will be able to"? For example:

> If you go to school, you will definitely be able to meet her.

Comment: You can, but "definitely" qualifies "be able to", not "meet her". In other words, you will be in a situation where you *can* meet her.

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree. "Definitely" modifies the whole verb phrase [be able to meet her]. "Be able" itself is not a constituent in this example.

Comment: @Nico in that case, the sentence would be "If you go to school, you will definitely meet her." What is the function of "be able to"? As stated, the sentence means that there is no guarantee, for example the person might be in a different class.

Comment: "Be able to" is a (modal) verb which requires a complement and cannot stand alone. Syntactically, your analysis is not correct all the more since adverbs do not "modify", but "specify".

Comment: @Nico, it was *you* who [used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529689/definitely-will-be-able-to?noredirect=1#comment1292907_529689) "modify" – I [used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529689/definitely-will-be-able-to?noredirect=1#comment1292887_529689) "qualify". My interpretation stands though. There is no certainty that there will be any meeting, whether or not you consider it to be a single phrase, since in your version "definitely" applies to "be able to meet her."

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, it was a typo. Nevertheless in linguistic terms, it is not "my version", but the way syntactic analysis operates. And no, "definitely" in this case expresses the committment of the utterer that the state of affairs will occur to a higher degree in comparison to a sentence where no such adverb occurs. You are confusing modality with tenses, and more precisely "irrealis" with "realis".

Comment: @Nico I fear that you may have overlooked what point that was actually made in the first place. The clarification simply boils down to that the only claim in this sentence is about the ability to meet someone, and that “definitely” makes that same claim stronger without making any claim that such a meeting will necessarily happen (it sounds like it could be up to the addressed person to to make it happen).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Sorry,I don't understand what point you disagree with.

Comment: @Nico I just tried to highlight the actual point that Weather Vane was making, as your responses were "I disagree", "no", etc. I have the impression that what you actually disagree with is a syntactical misstep in how they worded their explanation rather than the actual point they were making. Either way, they kept arguing that same point (as you said that you disagreed), not your syntactic corrections.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I don't see where Weather made a point that "definitely" reinforces the claim. To me, writing "you will be in a situation where you can meet her", as he does, does not cover the use of "definitely" vs. the same sentence without the adverb.

Comment: @Nico The first part, *"definitely" qualifies "be able to [meet her]", not "meet her" [in itself]* (edited to fix what I believe was your complaint), covers what role "definitely" has. The part that you quoted (which had explicit emphasis on *can*) just reiterates that even with "definitely" it's still a case of "you *can* meet", as opposed to "you *will* meet". I will not keep arguing this, but I hope you get the idea. I'm not saying that you are wrong, rather that you are arguing a different point than the one Weather Vane made.